# Fragment shader for unsigned integer textures

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-3, fragment-shader

I am using following shader for unsigned integer textures to read a data:
Fragment shader:

Code :

```
#version 150
out uvec4 fragColor;
uniform uint factor;
void main()
{
uint temp=factor;
temp=temp/2;
fragColor = uvec4(temp,temp,temp,temp);
}
```

But i am getting error on driver A:

"Compile failed.
ERROR: 0:7: '/' : Wrong operand types. No operation '/' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'uint' and a right operand of type 'const int' (and there is no acceptable conversion)
ERROR: 1 compilation errors. No code generated."

on driver B it runs perfectly. Is driver A is buggy or my shader is wrong? if wrong, how can i achieve the same result?

Comment: What happens if you just say: uint temp = factor / 2; and omit temp=temp/2; ?

Comment: Just found that this is true of the GLSL specs earlier than 4.0. GLSL 4.0 added an implicit conversion from signed to unsigned. AMD seems to use the same compiler for all shader versions when it comes to syntax and conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
temp = temp / uint(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

GLSL does not allow implicit conversions between signed and unsigned ints, so both operands of a binary operand must be the same.  Use:

```
temp = temp / 2u;
```

to use an unsigned int constant.